# How to provide template arguments to a lambda with a call operator template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

For c++20 it is proposed to add the following syntax for generic lambdas [p0428r2.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf)

```cpp
auto f = []<typename T>( T t ) {};
```

But the current implementation in gcc 8 did not accept the following instantiation:

```cpp
f<std::string>("");
```

Is that a implementation bug in gcc or a missing language feature? I know we talk about a proposal and not a approved specification.

Complete example ( with comparison to template function syntax ):

```cpp
template <typename T> void n( T t ) { std::cout << t << std::endl; }

auto f = []<typename T>( T t ) { std::cout << t << std::endl; };

int main()
{
    f<std::string>("Hello");  // error!
    n<std::string>("World");
}
```

complains with following error:

> main.cpp:25:22: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
>            f("Hello");

Comment: Note that part of the point of this feature is to allow constraining *extant* (thus deduced) template arguments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The result of a lambda expression is not a function; it is a function *object*. That is, it is a class type that has an `operator()` overload on it. So this:

```
auto f = []<typename T>( T t ) {};
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
struct unnamed
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T t) {}
};

auto f = unnamed{};
```

If you want to explicitly provide template arguments to a lambda function, you have to call `operator()` explicitly:

```cpp
f.operator()</* template arguments ... */>(parameters);
```

Comment: Note: you might need to add the `template` keyword in case you get an 'expected primary expression before < token'. That would be when the template type doesn't appear in the arguments and can't be deduced. So you would do something like:
`f.template operator()<template arguments>(parameters)`