# How can I make C++ invoke a templated operator() instead of using operator<

Tags: c++

In this code, GCC confuses my invocation of a generic lambda's `operator()` with a less-than operator:

```
void scale_vector(std::vector<int>& vector, int scale) {
    auto visitor = [&]<int scale_const>() {
        for (int& v : vs) {
            v *= scale_const;
        }
    };

    switch (scale) {
        case 1:
            visitor<1>();
            break;
        case 2:
            visitor<2>();
            break;
        case 3:
            visitor<3>();
            break;
        case 4:
            visitor<4>();
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid scale");
    }
}
```

GCC trunk gives this error output when I attempt to compile with `-O3 -std=c++20`:

```
<source>: In function 'void scale_vector(std::vector<int>&, int)':
<source>:14:20: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'scale_vector(std::vector<int>&, int)::<lambda()>' and 'int')
   14 |             visitor<1>();
      |             ~~~~~~~^~
      |             |       |
      |             |       int
      |             scale_vector(std::vector<int>&, int)::<lambda()>
<source>:14:24: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   14 |             visitor<1>();
      |                        ^
```

Ordinarily when this comes up it is possible to insert a `template` keyword before the name of a function template to indicate to GCC that I wish to treat this as a function template, not a value, but in this case this just leads to a different error because I don't think it parses as the lambda is not a template and is not a dependent type, it just has a templated `operator()`:

```
<source>: In function 'void scale_vector(std::vector<int>&, int)':
<source>:14:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'template'
   14 |             template visitor<1>(scale);
      |             ^~~~~~~~
```

How can I call this visitor code? Thanks!

Comment: `visitor.operator()<1>();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725745 may help you.

Comment: gcc doesn't confuse anything; `visitor` is not a template, it's just an ordinary object.

Comment: `vs` ? typo? should it be `vector` ?

Comment: Why template parameter at all? In this case it doesn't make seance. regular parameter will do the job in better way (case is not needed). Looks like over-engineered code. There is KISS rule.

Comment: Joining @MarekR – the entire lambda appears pretty meaningless to me: `if(1 <= scale && scale <= 4) { for(...) { v *= scale; } } else { throw ... }` – unless of course, you oversimplified a much more complex problem to produce a [mre]…

Comment: @Aconcagua I think plan was to have compile time constant so compiler would have more opportunities to optimize. Since multiplication is fast (3 ticks of CPU clock) and do not block anything like division I do not think this microoptimalization will achieve anything significant,  but in such cases there is basic rule "measure first".

Comment: @MarekR Would be curious how any such optimisation should look like – actually cannot imagine having either of a register or an encoded value as operand for multiplication being faster than the other. From that point of view I wouldn't expect any effect at all...

Comment: @Aconcagua The context of this question is almost certainly this blog post: https://voidstar.tech/code_duplication/ — however, the caveats from the [HN discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=37839326) apply (tl;dr: inlining the code negates any performance gain from convoluted templates).